# gitlab clone takes a lot of time

Tags: git, gitlab, clone

Im doing SSH git clone -

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:###############.git two3
```

for five minutes nothing happens, its stuck at

```
Cloning into 'two3'.
```

then it actually starts cloning. repo is about 35 MB size.

How to speed up the cloning.

this takes a long time

Comment: Does it take the same amount of time to clone the repository with HTTPS?

Comment: Can you try `git clone --depth 1 git@gitlab.com:###############.git two3`. How are you calculating the size of the repo?

Comment: HTTPS cloing has no issues; will done within 15 seconds.

Comment: git clone --depth 1 .............. This still faces the same issue, takes around 10 mins

Comment: Out of curiosity i ported from GitLab to GitHub. cloning is done within 10 seconds .. looks like some issue with GitLab itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aswering my own question This is due to Ipv6. It gets resolved when i am using -

```
echo "# To prefer IPv4 over everything else" >> /etc/gai.conf
echo "precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100" >> /etc/gai.conf
echo "precedence ::1/128 50" >> /etc/gai.conf
echo "precedence ::/0 40" >> /etc/gai.conf
echo "precedence 2002::/16 30" >> /etc/gai.conf
echo "precedence ::/96 20" >> /etc/gai.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [recent incident](https://status.gitlab.com/pages/history/5b36dc6502d06804c08349f7), with its [resolution ticket](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/production/-/issues/3925), which could explain some of what you are experiencing.
Plus the [SSH loadbalancer had some issues as well](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/production/-/issues/3878#note_525025336).

Check also if the issue persists for other GitLab repositories you would clone through SSH.

Comment: BTW just tried cloning again ... issue still present. I'am moving back to github

Comment: @keerthankumar OK, strange. Does this issue persists from another computer/other network for you?

Comment: Tried with another network as well! not sure another system

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue for long time, then I tried running this command `ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com` and it resolved the issue for me.
You should verify the authenticity of the GitLab host, if you are cloning for the first time.

Reference : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html